# Having problem converting object/string type date formats to datetime type

Tags: pandas

Please assist how to convert a complete column elements to datetime format in pandas dataframe. The below is one of the such element.

1-July-2020 7.30 PM

[DateTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFCyg.png)

Comment: Read the doc : [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and the `format` argument.

Comment: When Trying giving me this kind of results
0    NaT

Comment: [Welcome to Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :-)

Comment: Post your code, and show us what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and the `format` argument:

```
>>> df
              DateTime
0  1-July-2020 7.30 PM

>>> df.dtypes
DateTime    object
dtype: object
```

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%d-%B-%Y %I.%M %p')
```

Output result:

```
>>> df
             DateTime
0 2020-07-01 19:30:00

>>> df.dtypes
DateTime    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: getting this below error now, please assist

ValueError: time data '1-July-2020 8:38 PM' does not match format '%d-%B-%Y %I.%M %p' (match)

Comment: It's because this datetime uses ':' rather than '.'. You need to clean this before.

Comment: Thank you resolved.
Will let know for any issues.

Comment: Consider to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Done, new to this platform. Sorry